# How do I calculate the power consumption for a device that lists AC and DC voltage?

Tags: power

I have a device and on the bottom it says:

```
[VAC]: 100-240
[VDC]: 12
[A]: 0.5
```

I know P=VA but it seems like the answer would be either 6W or 50-120W, which seems like a major difference.

The device gets plugged into the wall (AC).

How much power can I expect it consume? Why do they list VAC and VDC if it can only be plugged into the wall?

Comment: Your missing the most important information. What is the device? My guess without any information is that it's 100-240VAC input with 12VDC output and max current of 500mA. A power brick?

Comment: `Why do they list VAC and VDC if it can only be plugged into the wall?` So that people don't put 12VDC into a device that is not rated for 12VDC as its input.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that this is a DC power supply that is designed to produce 12 volts at up to 0.5 amp, or 6 watts.  If so, the maximum AC input power should be a little over 6 watts, to allow for a little inefficiency.

The actual power consumption will depend on the load on the output.  If the load is only 0.25 amp or 3 watts, the AC input power should be a little over three watts.